# How do I cause a pseudo element to span over blank grid cells?

Tags: css, css-grid, pseudo-element

I have a Powerpoint-esque layout that I am trying to build in a responsive way using `display:grid`. I am using pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` to draw connecting lines between cells of the grid. This works fine when there cells are adjacent. However, sometimes I want to draw a line between two cells that may be a row or two away. In the attached example, I want the green line to span all the way from #2 to #7.

Is it possible to get the connecting pseudo-element to span the gap in a way that doesn't require hard-coding the height? I may come up with another class (e.g. `.double-height:after { height: <whatever the height of a cell plus margins is> }` but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 45% 10% 45%;
 }
 
.column-0 { grid-column-start: 1; grid-column-end: 2;}
.column-1 { grid-column-start: 3; grid-column-end: 4;}
.row-0 { grid-row-start: 1; grid-row-end: 2;}
.row-1 { grid-row-start: 2; grid-row-end: 3;}
.row-2 { grid-row-start: 3; grid-row-end: 4;}
.row-3 { grid-row-start: 4; grid-row-end: 5;}
.row-4 { grid-row-start: 5; grid-row-end: 6;}
.row-5 { grid-row-start: 6; grid-row-end: 7;}
.row-6 { grid-row-start: 7; grid-row-end: 8;}

.grid > * { 
  padding: 0.25em;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.line-down:after {
  content: '';
  position:absolute; 
  top:calc(100% + 5px);
  height: 20px;
  left:50%; 
  width:4px; 
  margin-left:-2px; 
  background:pink; 
  border-radius:2px; 
}
.column-1.row-1:after { background: #00ff00; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column-1 row-0 line-down">1</div>
  <div class="column-1 row-1 line-down">2</div>
  <div class="column-0 row-1 line-down">3</div>
  <div class="column-0 row-2 line-down">4</div>
  <div class="column-0 row-3 line-down">5</div>
  <div class="column-0 row-4 line-down">6</div>
  <div class="column-1 row-5 line-down">7</div>
  <div class="column-0 row-5">8</div>
  <div class="column-1 row-6">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `::after` pseudo-class

Comment: Doubtful...CSS has no way of *knowing* the relative positions of two unconnected elements to one another.

Comment: @MatheusSimões `::after` is a pseudo-element, not a pseudo-class. There's also no effective difference between how single-colon and double-colon pseudo-elements are interpreted by browsers. The difference is semantic to separate them from being considered by developers the same kind of thing as pseudo-classes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you're going for, since you haven't quite explained how dynamic your grid is or given any other use cases. This solution can be either hard-coded or more dynamic, so I think at the very least it can lead you in the right direction:

You can be clever about the `height` property using `calc()`, as long as you have some way for knowing the amount or rows gap (In your case it would be `7 - 2 = 5`. In this manner you can set the green line's `::after` pseudo-elements height in accordance with the following data: `rowHeight * 2 * rowsGap`, notice the multiplication by 2 because each row is doubled with a pseudo element. This can either be static with a set proportion you decide or dynamic if you use JS to determine `rowHeight` and `rowsGap` in your app / website.

Here's the actual css code:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 45% 10% 45%;
 }

.column-0 { grid-column-start: 1; grid-column-end: 2;}
.column-1 { grid-column-start: 3; grid-column-end: 4;}
.row-0 { grid-row-start: 1; grid-row-end: 2;}
.row-1 { grid-row-start: 2; grid-row-end: 3;}
.row-2 { grid-row-start: 3; grid-row-end: 4;}
.row-3 { grid-row-start: 4; grid-row-end: 5;}
.row-4 { grid-row-start: 5; grid-row-end: 6;}
.row-5 { grid-row-start: 6; grid-row-end: 7;}
.row-6 { grid-row-start: 7; grid-row-end: 8;}

.grid > * { 
  padding: 0.25em;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.line-down:after {
  content: '';
  position:absolute; 
  top:calc(100% + 5px);
  height: 20px;
  left:50%; 
  width:4px; 
  margin-left:-2px; 
  background:pink; 
  border-radius:2px; 
}
.column-1.row-1:after { 
  background: #00ff00;
  height: calc(20px * 10);
}
```

notice the change is only at the `.column-1.row-1:after` rule:

```
.column-1.row-1:after { 
  background: #00ff00;
  height: calc(20px * 10);
}
```

and here's a working js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wa01vz92/2/

Comment: This is a good idea. Its not exactly what I was hoping for but it should work. Since the CSS is where the elements are laid out in the grid, I think it is reasonable to allow the CSS to make additional assumptions about the length of the connection.